# Document.referrer for base domain

Tags: javascript

I know I can grab the entire referring url by using:

```
document.referrer
```

But how would I only grab the base domain of the referrer??  So:

```
if(document.referrer === subdomain.domain.com){

}
```

So all referring urls coming from that main domain would work and all strings coming after the base domain are ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At its simplest, just check `document.referrer.indexOf("example.com") > -1`. The downside of this is that if the referring page is `http://somethingevil.com/pages/example.com` then you'll get a false match on the check.

You could go for a regex, something like: `/^https?:\/\/example\.com\//` as this will be more reliable of a check, but a harder one to cover edge cases like subdomains, ports, accessing via the IP address, etc..

Comment: I think I'm going to have to go the regex route as the domain will more than likely occur elsewhere in the full URL.  How would this new if statement be written?  if(document.referrer.indexOf("/^https?:\/\/example\.com\//"){

Comment: Thanks, I actually went with a PHP route on this, but marking your answer as correct.